# Adding textmessages together depending on sender from an ArrayList [Android]

Tags: java, android

Okay, keep in mind that I'm new to Android and I'm simply put not any good at java.

I've got a method that checks through a list of sms's and add's sms messages that starts/ends with specified characters to an arrayList.

```
public boolean checkForKey(Object[] smsList) {
    //Go through sms list searching for key, add each that starts/ends with correct characters to an arrayList..
    //do something productive

    String str = "";
    for(int i= 0; i < smsList.length; i++){
        SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsList[i]);
        String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();

        if(body.startsWith("-?-") || body.endsWith("-?!-")){
            msgList.add(sms);
        }
    }

    if(msgList == null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

So basically what I want to do is pair together messages from a specified sender, I'll give an example as I'm not great at getting my point across:

David sends these two messages:

-?-
blajaheiuhfahiufeihuhiuhfuheuaiifahhafhbehb

and

kahefkhafkehauiefhiuahfeiuhaiefuhauiehiafhe
-?!-

so I want to put them together into a single string.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Okay, so updating my thoughtline,

```
String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();

        if(body.startsWith("-?-")) { //|| body.endsWith("-?!-")){
            str = body;
            // msgList.add(sms);
        }
        if(body.endsWith("-?1-")) {
            str += body;
        }
```

So say that str is equal to the first half of the message (key in my case), now I want to add the second half by finding the message that ends with -?!- and has the same address (sender)- how can I do this? I mean make sure they have the same sender?

Comment: How about StringBuilder ->  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Comment: Instead of checking for starting -?-  and ending -?!- in same if block, I would do that in different if blocks . Assign the value in the first one ie str = body and append in the second one ie str += body . and define str outside the method.

Comment: although, I know about the string builder, it's the actual finding the two corresponding messages from the sender.. assuming the messages wouldn't be in order?

Although just having thought of something, maybe one could do as you say Raman, to do the two different if blocks and another argument that checks if the end string has the same sender as the first.